# Help to convert the SQL query to Lambda(Linq)

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

Can anyone help me, to convert the below sql query to Linq (Lambda Expressions).
Thanks in Advance.

**SQL Query:**

> UPDATE A INNER JOIN B ON (A.Trade Number=B.Trade Number) AND
>   (A.AccountId=B.AccountId)  SET A.Float = B.CCY, A.Float = B.BASIS,
>   A.LastReset = B.FIXING, A.LastLibor = B.INTRATE;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates are not expressed as LINQ statements.  You can use LINQ to load the record you wish to modify, but the actual update will involve a separate method call, the details of which will depend on which database technology you're using.

So, assuming you already have a reference to the record you wish to update from A, load the associated record from B (using LINQ), perform the updates to A programatically, and then save the changes to A.

[Here](http://www.richardbushnell.net/2008/02/18/how-to-update-data-with-linq-to-sql/)'s an example using LINQ-to-SQL.